# How to assign equal revenue weight to every location of a company in a table? Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, conditional-statements

I am working on a problem where I have the following table:

```
 +----------+ | +------+ | +------------+
 company_id   | country  | total revenue

      1         Russia     1200

      2         Croatia    1200
      2         Italy      1200

      3         USA        1200
      3         UK         1200
      3         Italy      1200
```

There are 3 companies in this table, but company '2' and company '3' have offices in 2 and 3 countries respectively. All companies pay 1200 per month, and because company 2 has 2 offices it shows as if they paid 1200 per month 2 times, and because company 3 has 3 offices it shows as if it paid 1200 per month 3 times. Instead, I would like revenue to be equally distributed based on how many times company_id appears in the table. company_id will only appear more than once for every additional country in which a company is based.

Assuming each company always pays 1,200 per month, my desired output is:

```
 +----------+ | +------+ | +------------+
     company_id   | country  | total revenue

          1         Russia     1200

          2         Croatia    600
          2         Italy      600

          3         USA        400
          3         UK         400
          3         Italy      400
```

Being new to SQL, I was thinking this can maybe be done through CASE WHEN statement, but I only learned to use CASE WHEN when I want to output a string depending on a condition. Here, I am trying to assign equal revenue weight to each company's country, depending on in how many countries a company is based in.

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT company_id, country, 
  total_revenue / (COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY company_id)) AS total_revenue
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row company_id  country total_revenue    
1   1           Russia  1200.0   
2   2           Croatia 600.0    
3   2           Italy   600.0    
4   3           USA     400.0    
5   3           UK      400.0    
6   3           Italy   400.0
```

Comment: This work beautifully, thank you so much for sharing your knowledge with me, this is a very valuable lesson for me!